# Nuspec referencing a file in a folder named '.xxx'

Tags: nuget, nuspec

I'm trying to include a file in a NuGet package which is located in a folder named `.m2`. When I create a Nuspec file for this project, I include the following:

```
<files>
  <file src="$M2_REPO$\com\tunnelvisionlabs\antlr4-csharp\4.1\antlr4-csharp-4.1-complete.jar" target="tools"/>
</files>
```

I then use the following command line argument to `NuGet.exe` (launching via powershell):

```
-Prop 'M2_REPO=C:\Users\me\.m2\repository'
```

In this case, the specified jar file is not included in the resulting `.nupkg` file.

**I have narrowed the problem down to the name of the `.m2` folder.** If I copy the `.m2` folder to a new folder named `m2` in the same directory, and then replace `.m2` with `m2` in the command line argument, the jar file *is* included in the output. While it's straightforward to update the Maven `settings.xml` on my local machine to redirect the `.m2` folder to a folder named `m2`, this configuration results in a project that is not easily built on other user's machines.

**Is there a way to update the `.nuspec` file or the command line argument so that NuGet will properly package a file located under a folder named `.m2`, without changing the name of the folder?**

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `-NoDefaultExcludes` parameter for `nuget pack`

```
nuget pack Foo.nuspec -NoDefaultExcludes
```